# iPhone - Mail composer kind of view

Tags: iphone, email

In iPhone default Applicaton "Mail", it has a compose view, where user can add text as well as image. Is there any component that accepts text as well as images?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at three20, [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) might be what you need.